# Sort storage files by modified date in Laravel

Tags: laravel, date, sorting, storage

I'm building a personal blog using Laravel 8, where the articles are displayed from `.md` files (no database). Everything works perfectly, but I'm struggling to sort those `.md` files by the `modified date` or `creation date`. Files are placed into the `storage` folder

Current code:

```
        // Getting files from storage:
        $files = Storage::disk('articles')->allFiles();
        $articles = [];

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $storage = Storage::disk('articles')->get($file);
            array_push($articles, $storage);
            $collection = collect($articles);
        }

        $array = collect($articles);
        $articles = $this->paginate($array);

        return view('pages.home', compact('articles'));
```

I've tried to get file details using the `filemtime()` function, but I get the following error:

```
$filePath = Storage::path($file);
$fileDate = filemtime($filePath);
dd($fileDate);
```

```
ErrorException
filemtime(): stat failed for C:\my-project\storage\app\article-file.md
```

`stat` function returns the same error.

Storage is linked, file exists, it returns the right path...

I'm out of ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Laravel already has method to read last modify file metadata

```
Storage::lastModified($name);
```

Link to documantation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-metadata